# Making a custom widget that includes a tinymce and works in Site Origin Page Builder

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, tinymce, visual-editor

For a client I'm using Site Origins Page Builder plugin. It enables the client to make rich layouts for each page by dragging and dropping widgets. Site Origin widgets that require a WYSIWYG-editor use the Black Studio TinyMCE plugin to include that feature.

In the past I've made some plugins that extend the Site Origin default widget class to add a TinyMCE to my widget. For the current plugin I'm building I require 3 TinyMCE fields. Therefor it's not feasible to merely extend the SO default widget class.

Using the info found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-use-bstw-within-plugin-custom-widget) I managed to get the a part of the tinyMCE loaded. The buttons above the textarea (in both visual and text) are not present. When I try switching from text view to visual view I end up with the following javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined
```

I'm pretty sure I need to require another javascript file that "fixes" the default TinyMCE behavior. I am however stuck in how to do this.

**Alternatively** I can include my own TinyMCE version/instance in the plugin. However, I find this to be undesirable because of the following reasons:

- Black Studio TinyMCE is already installed as well as the default Wordpress TinyMCE. Requiring 3 wysiwyg-editors doesn't seem like the best approach.
- The default TinyMCE and the Black Studio one are very close visually which is great from a UX perspective. However, adding yet another TinyMCE will result in either a degradation of UX or will require me to style it exactly like the other 2 (which is like reinventing the wheel).